# Comparative advantages of xdoc and apt formats

Tags: maven-2, apt, xdoc

What are the relative merits of the xdoc and apt formats for writing websites of Maven projects? Is one more expressive than the other? Has one got better tool support than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XDOC format is definitely a richer mechanism for creating documents and is required if you want to produce documents with TOC/TOF, headers, footers or footnotes (and other document attributes), since the APT format doesn't support these.

That being said, I tend to use the APT format for almost all internal documents as I enjoy writing in the APT format.  When compared to writing XDOC (with all its XML loveliness), APT is a breeze.  By the same token, when I'm writing a plugin that generates content, I tend to use the XDOC format, since it's pretty easy to write software that creates the required XML.

Answer (score 0):

APT format is easy to use. However, it does not support custom styling (for example styling a character or a heading). The closest to preformatted text that you can use with APT is the "verbatim text"
Like in HTML, verbatim text is preformatted. Unlike HTML, verbatim text is escaped: inside a verbatim display, markup is not interpreted by the APT processor.